# why does this code insert multiple records instead of one

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i am trying to insert some info into an sql server table but instead of inserting one record it inserts multiple records :

```
string fileName1 = "imgs/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string fileName2 = "imgs/" + FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;
    string fileName3 = "imgs/" + FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName;
    string fileName4 = "imgs/" + FileUpload4.PostedFile.FileName;

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AHMED-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO img (img) VALUES (@img)", conn);
    conn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", fileName1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", fileName2);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", fileName3);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", fileName4);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    conn.Close();
```

**it adds 8 or more records instead of 4**

using asp.net 4

thanks

Comment: @CD i didn't clarify right i mean instead of 4 times 8 times, sorry

Comment: Please post your complete code. I doubt this method is called two times.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar this is the full code

Comment: Time to break out the debugger and step through this. Is it possible this routine is being called twice?

Comment: Theres not enough information here to see why it might be getting run more then once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably calling the function twice.

Comment: Agreed.  Add a breakpoint at the top of this method and make sure it is only called once.  If it is and you are still getting 8 or more inserts, let us know (and give us the exact number of inserts please).

Answer (score 1):

You're executing this statement four times.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

cmd represents one SQL INSERT statement.

```
cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO img (img) VALUES (@img)", conn);
```

Execute one INSERT four times, and unless you violate a constraint you get four rows.

Comment: again my mistake didnt clarify i mean instead of executing 4 times it executes 8 or more